# WebStorm index.html file doesn't have any shortcuts or auto completion. Why?

Tags: webstorm

WebStorm `index.html` file doesn't have any shortcuts or auto completion. Why?

If I create any other html file it will be fully functional but when it is `index.html` it is just grey: no coloring, no auto completion or shortcuts.

Does anyone know the reason for that?

Comment: Screenshots please (of the whole IDE window) where I can clearly see the file itself , it's name and icon. Using Default theme please -- and not custom like Material/Afterglow that uses custom icons etc.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if `index.html` is added to text file patterns in **Preferences | Editor | File types -> Text** file type. Removing this pattern should solve your problem